# Failed to return the value of a cell in a Worksheet in an XLWorkbook

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

It turns out that two cells assigned two different dates; to cells A2 and B2 I assign them the values 3/28/2015 and 3/29/2015, respectively (This from c #, to be clear).

Then, to cell A3 I apply a formula. What I do is the following:

```
ws.Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SIFECHA(R[-1]C[0],R[-1]C[1],\"md\")";
```

When I try to access the value of said cell from c # using the following instruction:

```
ws.Cell("A3").Value;
```

I get an exception, it seems that due to the data conversion failure ...

*Value = '((ClosedXML.Excel.XLCell)y).Value' threw an exception of type 'System.Exception'*

The code:

```
var Dates = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("28/03/2015","29/03/2015"),                                   
};
XLWorkbook workbook = await Task.FromResult(Dates.ToBook());
var ws = workbook.Worksheet("Report");           
ws.Cell("A3").DataType = XLCellValues.Number; // a try failed                
ws.Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=ENTERO(SIFECHA(R[-1]C[0],R[-1]C[1],\"md\"))";          
ws.Cell("A3").Select();
ws.Cell("A3").SetActive(true); //another try
ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
var y = ws.ActiveCell.Value; //and here the code exploid
```

Any contribution would be of great help to me. Thank you very much. Sorry for my English, I speak Spanish

Comment: Hey Necroyeti! Welcome to StackOverflow! Would it be possible for you to post a more complete example of the code that produces this problem? If you check out [mcve], you'll have a better idea of what we need to help you solve this!

Comment: I do not know how I can be clearer. Cell A3 after applying that formula is "corrupt" so to speak. I could upload images to imgur, or the fragment of the code since I created the Workbook until I try to return the value of the cell. What sounds better?

Comment: It's not that you're unclear at all, in fact, this is one of the better questions I've seen in a while. If you could copy/paste more of your code in your question, that would be great! It helps us to have a bit more context of what might be causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, then I'll edit the question right now

Comment: What version of ClosedXML are you using? Try the latest, which is at time of writing v0.93.0-beta4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying, they force me to implement "brute force" using Excel offered by Microsoft importing the library ---> `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` <---

And the code like that:

```
    public static Application App;
    public static Workbook Wb;
    public static Worksheet Ws;
    public static object GetGetTimeElapsed(string Fecha_Inicio, string Fecha_Fin)
    {
        try
        {
            if (App == null)
            {
                App = new Application();
                Wb = App.Workbooks.Add();
                Ws = (Worksheet)Wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            }               
            Ws.Cells[1, 1].Formula = "=DATEDIF(\"" + Fecha_Inicio + "\",\"" + Fecha_Fin + "\",\"MD\")";
            Ws.Cells[1, 2].Formula = "=DATEDIF(\"" + Fecha_Inicio + "\",\"" + Fecha_Fin + "\",\"YM\")";
            Ws.Cells[1, 3].Formula = "=DATEDIF(\"" + Fecha_Inicio + "\",\"" + Fecha_Fin + "\",\"Y\")";
            double DaysElapsed = Ws.Cells[1, 1].Value;
            double MonthsElapsed = Ws.Cells[1, 2].Value;
            double YearsElapsed = Ws.Cells[1, 3].Value;
            var List = new
            {
                Days = DaysElapsed,
                Months = MonthsElapsed,
                Years = YearsElapsed
            };
            return new { List.Days, List.Months, List.Years };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new BaseException(ex);
        }           
    }
```

Work perfectly, thanks for your contributions!

Answer (score 2):

Formulas written to Excel using the FormulaR1C1 and Formula property must be writen in US English syntax entirely.

Comment: The same result Try the following formula `"= DATEDIF (R [-1] C [0], R [-1] C [1], \" Y \ ")"` But nothing. I do not believe that the language affects, previously I had tried a sum more or less like this "= SUMA (...)" with satisfactory results.

Comment: That does not look like a valid formula. Write the formula in a cell. Make sure it does what you need. Then open the VBA editor, open the immediate pane and type: ?ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 and hit enter. This is the syntax you need. Surround it with double-quotes and double-up all existing quotes in the formula to make it work for the programing language.

Comment: Is that the cell stays with the formula. After downloading the file, the cell has the result of said formula, and when I click on it, the formula appears well applied. Untill there, normal. The problem arises when asking about the value of said cell in c # after having applied the formula

Comment: Aha, I've just proven I know zilch about C#. The \ is the escape character to handle the " 's in the formula.If calculation is set to manual in your code, the result of the formula will probably be wrong. Set calc to auto before reading the cell values.